# Shorter way to get rid of `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode)`?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, hyperref

I am using `\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}` command over-and-over in my document and for that I have created a new command `\NewDocumentCommand {\ru}{+m}{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}`.

Now, as soon as I use this `\ru` in places like `\section`, XeLaTeX throws the (in)famous error

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\ru' on input line XXX.
```

To fix that, we of course have `\texorpdfstring` but the issue is that I have to type it so many times, and such a big glob of text makes the whole document unreadable. For example, to get rid of this warning, I have to type `\texorpdfstring{\ru{ъ}}{ъ}` where a simple `\ru{ъ}` would have done the trick.

To fix this, I created another command:

```
\NewDocumentCommand {\sru}{+m}{\texorpdfstring{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}{#1}}
```

This command, presumably, would have gotten rid of the error. However, now I am getting the error:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\sru' on input line XXX.
```

Is there any way to shorten this whole structure *and* get rid of the above warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` so it expands and the texorpdf switch is seen at the right time.